# How to update ios web clip application

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

I'm developing mobile web application (mobile version of out site). And there is a good availability to add this site to desktop at iphone, for example (web clip), for future launching it from desktop icon. 
But the problem is when i add some changes to image sprite, it does not updates in web clip application. However in safari (after page refresh) it works good.

Is there any way to update web clip?

Comment: If I understand this correctly you're doing the "Add to Homescreen" action on Safari and essentially turning the website into a shortcut on the home screen correct?  If so, all you have to do is repeat the process to re-download the new data.

Comment: yes, you are right. But should i tell all users to repeat this process ? =)

Comment: Well of course, but you shouldn't be treating such a shortcut as an app.

Comment: not sure, i understand you...
but i think there should be resolution for refreshing web clip appl anyway... what if i update my mobile site? i really need to update it in web clip too...

Comment: You need to tell everyone to repeat the "Add to Homescreen" process, but you really shouldn't rely on this to be used as an application as it isn't very user friendly to update.